# A better way of performing replace on a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, replace

Let's say I have a string in one cell that is like this:

```
{IR1} {IR2} some text {IR3} some more text {IR6} {IR7}
```

I want to replace all {IR1} to {IR7} with known values from another table.

What is the most efficient way of replacing all IRX substrings with knows replacements values?

At the moment I can replace replace the number of replace values in that table: like `Replace(Replace(Replace.......)...)...)..)`, however I want to know if there is anything better than this.

Comment: I also only know `Replace(Replace(Replace.......)...)...)..)`...

Comment: A better way is to use (on client side) `string.Format("bla {0} bla bla {1} bla bal bla {2} ", bla1, bla2, bla3)` function.

Comment: This would be performed inside stored procedure. So I can't use client side.